# Google Analytics not capturing outgoing image links

Tags: google-analytics

When a user clicks on an outgoing text link in my wordpress blog, I can see it in the real time stats and in the daily stats that it was clicked and how many times it was clicked. However, I have ads on the site as well, that are just outgoing links from an image, and these are not captured by Google Analytics.

I have searched and see no reason there should be a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some code to track outbound link clicks. You haven't shared it, but I'm guessing you do and that's the one tracking the image clicks.

That code will probably not work on ads because the ads exist inside an iframe that can't be inspected by the code you have on the page.

Maybe the ad network provides an API you can use, to identify events like clicks on the Ads. Otherwise you're stuck and there's simply no way to detect clicks inside that iframe.